# Running both sensor and addressable LED strips at a same time?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, led, c++

I'm trying to obtain the sensors' readings as well as making the LED strips to light up at this particular pattern, if the sensor readings reaches certain values. But since both of these codes are inside the void `loop()`, there will be a problem. How can I do this correctly?

```C++
void loop()
{    
    currentSensorReading = analogRead(sensorPin);
    Serial.println(currentSensorReading );

    if(currentSensorReading is in range of certain values){
        rainbowCycle(20);
    } else { turn LEDs off }
}

void rainbowCycle(uint8_t wait) {
  uint16_t i, j;

  for(j=0; j<256*5; j++) { // 5 cycles of all colors on wheel
    for(i=0; i< strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, Wheel(((i * 256 / strip.numPixels()) + j) & 255));
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);
  }
}
```

Comment: Cross-posted on [Arduino Forum](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=345716)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite without using `delay()`. Or alternatively, do the test inside the `for` loop as well, eg.

```C++
void rainbowCycle(uint8_t wait) {
  uint16_t i, j;

  for(j=0; j<256*5; j++) { // 5 cycles of all colors on wheel
    for(i=0; i< strip.numPixels(); i++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(i, Wheel(((i * 256 / strip.numPixels()) + j) & 255));
    }
    strip.show();
    delay(wait);

    // ----------- ADD THESE THREE LINES ---------------
    currentSensorReading = analogRead(sensorPin);
    if(currentSensorReading is NOT in range of certain values)
        return;

  }
}
```